# Bounded Derivative Test

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I'm currently working on a question in an assignment, and it asks us to use the bounded derivative test, to determine whether $$f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $(0,1)$.

The derivative $f'$ is not bounded; does this imply that $f$ is **not** uniformly continuous?

Also, in the second part of the question it asks us to do the same with $$f(x)=x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$, I need a worked solution to compare with mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! Actually $$\text{bounded derivative $\Longrightarrow$ uniform continuity } $$ is true with some assumption. . The equivalent true statement is $$\text{non uniform continuity $\Longrightarrow$ non bounded derivative} $$ The statement   $$\text{non bounded derivative $\Longrightarrow$ non uniform continuity } $$ is **false**. For example take $$f:[0,\infty) \ni x \mapsto \sqrt{x} \in \Bbb{R}$$ is uniformly continuous but the derivative is unbounded near zero.

---

Actually your $f$ is not uniform continuous on $(0,1)$. For,take $$x_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n \pi} \;\; \text{and}\;\;y_n=\frac{1}{\frac{3\pi}{2}+2n \pi}$$   Then $\vert x_n - y_n \vert \rightarrow o$ whereas $\vert f(x_n)-f(y_n) \vert $ is not!

---

The derivative of the second one is $$f'(x)=\sin (\frac{1}{x})-\frac{1}{x}\cos (\frac{1}{x})$$

Is it bounded? Note that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$

Comment: Thanks so much! Surely the same applies for the second one?

Comment: can you calculate the derivative of the second one? the second one is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$!

Comment: After about five minutes, yes, I was able to calculate the derivative, but for the first one, is it a good idea to literally write $|f'|\leq K$ where $K$ doesn't exist, i.e it's unbounded. You know what I mean? Since $f'\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$, it's unbounded to the left? It's still quite fresh in my mind, so I'm still getting used to it

Comment: Yes! the derivative of first is not bounded! If it were, then $f$ is uniform continuous on $(0,1)$ which is false. Your guess is right!